# Ms Sql Check linkedserver connection check from trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, connection, linked-server

I'm trying to create a trigger which will insert some data into a table on a linkedserver in Ms Sql 2012. I want to be able to check if the server connection is active and if it isn't then I want to log the message else where but not abort the entire transaction and roll back. I want the query which started the trigger to continue.

I tried the method described here 
[How to test linkedserver's connectivity in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191193/how-to-test-linkedservers-connectivity-in-tsql)
This does sort of work but the error is still thrown and my transaction is rolled back with the message.

> An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back.

An error is thrown on anything involving a downed linkedserver which causes a rollback no matter what and a CATCH doesn't seem to stop it.

Example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TEST1_TRG]
   ON  [dbo].[Test1]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @srvr nvarchar(128), @retval int;
    set @srvr = 'loopback';
    begin try
        exec @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @srvr;
    end try
    begin catch
        set @retval = sign(@@error);
    end catch;
    print @retval
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this

```
-- All your Code

BEGIN TRY
-- place Query which fires the trigger Here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- Check for the trigger error and if it is trigger error 
  --  do nothing
  --  else raise an error
END CATCH

-- The subsequenet Code
```

Now the catch block will get the error, but as there will be no code in catch block, it will go to the subsequent code.

Comment: I don't have control over the calling queries, they can come from any where. So I can really only work within the context of my trigger.